# Angular external script is loaded only on first page open

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Me loading an external script in a project in angular, through the file **angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/mask.js"
            ],
```

It is a script to apply a mask to some form fields. When the page is first loaded the script works, if I navigate to another page without refreshing and go back to the page containing the form it no longer works.

Is there another way to load this script whenever that component is accessed?

Remembering that the site works as a SPA (Single Page Application), so navigation between pages occurs without the need for new requests.

There are several masks, I run them through a function, see:

```
function id(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
window.onload = function() {
    id('nome')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        inicialMaiuscula(this);
    });
    id('telefone')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        mascara(this, mtel);
    });
    id('celular')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        mascara(this, mtel);
    });
    id('cep')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        mascara(this, cepm);
    });
    id('cep')?.addEventListener("change", function() {
        getEndereco(this);
    });
    id('cpf')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        mascara(this, cpf_mask);
    });
    id('cpf')?.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        validarCPF(this.value);
    });
    id('cpf')?.addEventListener("paste", function() {
        return false;
    });
    id('rg')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        mascara(this, soNumeros);
    });
    id('nascimento')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        mascara(this, data);
    });
    id('usuario')?.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        letrasNumeros(event);
    });
    id('senha')?.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        validaSenha(this);
    });
    id('confSenha')?.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        validaSenha(this);
    });
    id('estado')?.addEventListener("input", function() {
        tudoMaiuscula(event);
    });
}
```

**Full mask.js:** https://jsfiddle.net/m50o6fn8/

Comment: Can you share the code of mask.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lets first understand, why does it work in the beginning?

The way JS/jQuery code would work is, your script is getting into action after `DOM Ready`(DOMContentLoaded). Suppose you've written a line `$('input[mask]').mask(...)` to apply masking. So when this line executes, it queries, and finds elements that match the selector, and applies the `mask` function to them. That's why it worked at page load.

### Why did it not work later?

Of course, as we have seen, the script already ran. Its an SPA. So the static script resource you mentioned in `angular.json`'s `scripts` option. It loads once on page load, so the next page visit won't re-execute or download the script. Cool.

### How to make it work?

The most recommended way here is using Angular Directive. WHY? because we wanted to add behavior(masking) on top of the DOM. Excellent. So what happens is when you write a directive, you will be mentioning the selector like `input[mask]`, so angular make sure that whenever any content is loaded on pages. and it matches the selector, it applies the behavior return inside directive class.

#### Simple Example

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[mask]',
})
export class MaskInputDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Input() format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).mask(this.format);
  }
}
```

An interesting fact to note in directive is `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook should be used to get hold of elements it is acting upon. And you can easily get hold of `element` by asking for `dependency` inside `constructor` like `private el: ElementRef`

---

But why re-invent the wheel? when things are already in a place. I would recommend you to use [**`ngx-mask`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) npm library instead.

Comment: Perfect your explanation, I added the snippet of the file that calls the functions. Isn't there a way to use this ready-made base and just call the functions inside the component? Because otherwise I would have to rewrite everything, practically.

Comment: `ngx-mask` is a fantastic library. I'll second that suggestion!

Comment: Great to know it helped.yes initially you create a directive as I suggested, I try to put your code.. otherwise ngx-mask is way to go. You will find everything you need. Just import and use

Comment: @PankajParkar Your tip is super valid, but what if I need to execute a function in jquery that doesn't exist in ngx-mask, how do I make it work whenever I access a certain component? For example, I have a function there that does validation in addition to the mask, so I would need to run it together in the same way.

Comment: @Clebson you can create a directive for that, as suggested in the answer

Comment: @PankajParkar I tried to follow your example, and I did like this: [https://jsfiddle.net/8y1e5vz0/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/8y1e5vz0/2/) I kept loading the script from the **angular.json** file but it didn't work. However if I put an `alert` on the `keyup` event defined in `ngAfterViewInit`, it works and even returns the function to me. I'm just not able to apply it in the input field.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should find out the code snippet that is applying the mask to the form field from mask.js file. It should look like `$('input').mask(...)`.

And then you should add that code snippet to `OnInit` or `AfterContentInit` lifecycle of each component you want to use it.

Btw it would be better to use a npm library instead of JS assets, i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask